# Why is equivalent for a sequence to be an $A$-sequence or to be an $A/I$-sequence?

Tags: commutative-algebra, abstract-algebra

Exercise 24.1 in Matsumura's commutative ring theory:

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring, and $I$ an ideal of $A$; assume that $I^r=0$, and that $I^i/I^{i+1}$ is a free $A/I$-module for $1\leq i < r$. Then for $x_1,\ldots,x_s\in A$, it is equivalent for $(x_1,\ldots,x_s)$ to be an $A$-sequence or an $A/I$-sequence.

My attempts: following hints, I showed that $\mathrm{Ass}_A(A/I^i) = \mathrm{Ass}(A/I)$ for all $i\geq 1$. In particular, $\mathrm{Ass}_A(A) = \mathrm{Ass}_A(A/I)$ because $I^r = 0$. However, this just says that an element of $A\setminus I$ is $A$-regular if and only if it is $A/I$-regular. We have to consider regular "seqeunces." How do we proceed?